# Extremely concerned with Puzzling.SE answer quality

Tags: discussion, support, beta-sites

It's quickly turning into Yahoo Answers.

Question quality is getting better. That isn't the issue.

The issue is answer quality.

Most users will disagree with me, but the quality of answers on that site is getting closer and closer to that of Y! Answers.   Much of this has to do with solving puzzles.  People will argue that solving puzzles requires lateral thinking, that there's no "one" solution.  I can agree with that, but they go on, saying that since anything goes, anything is an acceptable answer.

This means we get extremely low quality answers that don't really answer questions well but sound like they were created by ignorant children. We get answers like the [following](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/4708/4425):

> I entered the maze, intrigued by the difficulty caused by the fact
>   that the exit was blocked off by a wall. Attached to my belt, I had
>   one less powerful grenade and two more powerful grenades. I was glad
>   to find out that the walls were made of a less sturdy material,
>   meaning that a grenade could easily knock down the wall. I tested the
>   weak grenade on an unnecessary wall, and to my delight, it worked! I
>   proceeded by using a larger grenade on the wall that was blocking the
>   exit. Not to my delight, there was a police officer guarding the exit!
>   I used my last grenade and ran towards the exit. I made it out of the
>   maze successfully.

Like seriously, that answer sounds so stupid to the question, yet it still received overwhelming community support, at least more than I thought possible. Creativity should not be an excuse for low-quality answers.

Meta.puzzling.stackexchange is hard for me, because there seems to be less and less of a unified community support to enforce strong rules in the community. People are using the "it's a young site, it's a beta, it's a new site" excuse to let bad answers and bad questions off the hook. I really don't know where to take this. From what I can tell, the mods I trying their best to take care of this but it doesn't look like anything will be changed soon.

That's why I'm asking you guys. I'm not sure what you think, but I'd like to hear from your opinions what you make of this.  I think it's especially noticeable when you have puzzling.SE questions constantly hitting the Hot Questions list, yet the quality you see is completely outrageous.

Comment: I agree with you that the answer quality there is the equivalent of decorating turds from the gas station restrooms around New York, but here is really not the place to discuss it.

Comment: Notice my comment there as to my disappointment with the *question* itself. That answer is actually the page's saving grace. I'd suggest finding a better example that isn't absolutely hilarious.

Comment: Personally I give Puzzles a pass (no down voting for content) to not stem anyone's creativity. It *is* a new site, will not solve any real life problems and is just for fun. The accepted answer will never be (Yahoo'ed) overcome by it. I say this with the utmost objective sincerity: if you don't like having fun and cracking jokes don't go there; it deserves an atmosphere a little less than the ordinarily stifling SE sites.

Comment: @Mazura If you want an atmosphere that's "fun", I would suggest Y! Answers.  StackExchange is ALWAYS about quality over quantity; this is why we have many rules set up throughout all sites to enforce that

Comment: Agree it's on topic here and voted to Leave Open but I fear it won't stay open for long. My advice is to contact a Community Manager directly (chat or even email) and ask for advise/help from him/her. (they are listed [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99341/152859) and most have their email address published)

Comment: It is a **beta site**. If no proper community and rules emerge, it'll be shut down. By the sound of it, it is headed that way, and I wouldn't worry.

Comment: This is quite specific to Puzzling at the moment, and I think it's really more appropriate for that Meta; I understand, however, that this topic is already open there, and you don't feel that it's being considered properly. _That_ -- the more general question -- would be a great subject for Meta.SE, though. "Beta site seems to be taking a quality dive, and per-site Meta discussion reveals that it's not perceived as a problem; is there more that I can do?" I'd be quite happy to vote to reopen this given a little editing to abstractify.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Will do, thanks for the advice.

Comment: @Mazura thank God for people like you. Puzzling certainly has its own spirit about it